# Muliple Dropdown Select option in Drupal8 Custom Form

Tags: forms, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-forms, form-api

I have to design the form with following fields

1. Country
2. State
3. District

If you select **Country** the Country value will be loaded in the Country Dropdown Field
Then if you select **State** the States belongs to Countries value will be loaded in the State Dropdown.
After that If you select District the Districts value belongs to States  will be loaded in the District Dropdown field.

I have tried but not work properly

```
 $form['Country'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Country'),
    '#description' => t('Country'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $countries,
    // '#default_value' => setInConfigandGEtVAlue,
    '#ajax' => ['callback' => [$this, 'getStates'], 'event' => 'change',
    'method' => 'html',
    'wrapper' => 'states-to-update',
    'progress' => [
    'type' => 'throbber',
    'message' => NULL,
    ],
    ],
    ];
    
    $states = [];
    // if($default_country != "") { load default states of selected country by get the default va
    lue of country (setInConfigandGEtVAlue)
    // $states = $this->getStatesByCountry($default_country);
    // }
    $form['state'] = array(
    '#title' => t('State'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#description' => t('Select the state'),
    '#options' => $states,
    // '#default_value' => setInConfigandGEtVAlue,
    '#attributes' => ["id" => 'states-to-update'],
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#validated' => TRUE
    );
    

$district_opt_records = [];


$form['districts'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('District Name'),
'#options' => $district_opt_records,
'#required' => TRUE,
'#attributes' => ["id" => 'district-to-update'],
'#validated' => TRUE,);

 
    public function getStates(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $triggeringElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    $value = $triggeringElement['#value'];
    $states = $this->getStatesByCountry($value);
    $wrapper_id = $triggeringElement["#ajax"]["wrapper"];
    $renderedField = '';
    foreach ($states as $key => $value) {
    $renderedField .= "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
    }
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand("#".$wrapper_id, $renderedField));
    return $response;
    }
    public function getStatesByCountry($default_country) {
    //add you logic return states by country
    return $states;
    }
```

The above code working only Countries and State but not able to get District values

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: No error message

Comment: Second time the Ajax calling function not working. It is working only one time